$f(x) = (\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k)^{\frac1n}$ is sublinear if $a_k \ge 0, x \ge 0$, i.e. $f(a + b) \le f(a) + f(b)$ for $a, b \ge 0$.
$f(x) = (\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k)^{\frac1n}$ is sublinear if $a_k \ge 0, x \ge 0$, i.e.  $f(a + b) \le f(a) + f(b)$ for $a, b \ge 0$.
I have some solution. I know that there's a very short and cute solution because it's from not very hard olympiad or is a part of problem from olympiad (unfortunatelly I don't know what the olympiad is). I'm more interested in a hint then in a full solution, but full solution is also interesting.
My solution:
Put $P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$. We want to show that $$\frac{f(a)}{f(a+b)} + \frac{f(b)}{f(a+b)} \ge 1  \Leftrightarrow \sqrt[n]{\frac{P_n(a)}{P_n(a+b)}} + \sqrt[n]{\frac{P_n(b)}{P_n(a+b)}} \ge 1$$
It's sufficient to prove that $$\sqrt[n]{\frac{P_n(a)}{P_n(a+b)}} \ge \frac{a}{a+b}.$$
But
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{P_n(a)}{P_n(a+b)}} \ge \frac{a}{a+b}  \Leftrightarrow  \frac{P_n(a)}{P_n(a+b)} \ge \frac{a^n}{(a+b)^n} \Leftrightarrow \frac{P_n(a)}{a^n} \ge \frac{P_n(a+b)}{(a+b)^n}$$
It's equivalent to say that $\frac{P_n(x)}{x^n}$ is nonincreasing, but $\frac{P_n(x)}{x^n} = a_n \frac{1}{x^n} + a_1 \frac{1}{x^{n-1}}+\ldots$  is nonincreasing as a sum of nonincreasing functions.
It looks like second derivatives do not help, though there are other problems where $f''$ helps, e.g.:
If the second derivative $f''(x)\ge 0$ then $f(\frac{a+b}{2})\le \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$
If $f(0)=0$ and $f''\ge 0$, then $f(a+b)\ge f(a)+f(b)$

Your approach can be simplified:
$$
 \frac{f(x)}{x} = \left( \frac{a_0}{x^n} + \ldots + \frac{a_{n-1}}{x} + a_n\right)^{1/n}
$$
is nonincreasing. It follows that
$$
 f(a) \ge \frac{a}{a+b} f(a+b)
$$
and
$$
 f(b) \ge \frac{b}{a+b} f(a+b)
$$
and therefore $f(a)+f(b) \ge f(a+b)$ for $a, b > 0$. This inequality holds also if $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Thank you very much! It looks like it's the original solution - it's very short

@SergeiNikolaev: You are welcome. – Btw, concave functions $F$ with $F(0) \ge 0$ also have the property that $F(x)/x$ is nonincreasing, which implies that they are sublinear. So there is some connection, but your $f$ is not necessarily concave.

@ Martin R. It looks like it's supposed that $F(x)/x$ is decreasing. Is this fact obvious or it is a problem? My ideas: if $F$ is concave then $F'$ is decreasing and we want to show that $(F(x)/x) ' < 0 \Leftrightarrow xF'(x) < F(x)$ and it's not obvious

@ Martin R. Oh, maybe this way: Lagrange's theorem $\Rightarrow F(x) - F(0) = (x-0)F'(\xi) \ge (x-0)F'(x)  \Rightarrow F(x) \ge F(x) - F(0) \ge xF'(x)$. It interesting!

Derivatives are not needed. If $F$ is concave with $F(0) \ge 0$ then
$$
F(x) \ge \frac{y-x}{y}F(0) + \frac x y F(y) \ge \frac x y F(y)
$$
for $0 < x < y$.

@ Martin R. Indeed, thank you!
